# Multiple model error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

I have an application that has three models: `company`, `university` and `formation`.

Relations between these three models are:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :formations, dependent: :destroy
end 

class University < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :formations, dependent: :destroy
end 

class Formation < ActiveRecord::Base
    #company
    belongs_to :company
    #universities
    belongs_to :university


    def company_name
      (company or university).try(:name)
    end

    def company_name=(name)
      company_or_university = University.where(name: name).first
      company_or_university ||= Company.where(name: name).first_or_create
      self.company = company_or_university
    end
end
```

So in this application I want to dropdown a list of universities and companies in the same field for formation form that is why I'm using this code in my formation form:

```
<% companies_or_universities = (Company.all.pluck(:name) + University.all.pluck(:name)).sort %>
<%= f.text_field :company_name, data: {autocomplete_source: companies_or_universities}, required: true, class: "form-control form-newjob" %>
```

this code works fine, but the problem is when I try to create a new formation and chose university name, I'm getting this error

> Company(#-650866168) expected, got University(#-647908008)

for `self.company = company_or_university`. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is quite explanatory: you cannot use a `Company` association to store a `University`, since the expected object is a `Company`.

I believe that you'll get the result you are looking for if you rewrite your setter like this:

```
class Formation < ActiveRecord::Base
  def company_name=(name)
    university_from_name = University.where(name: name).first

    if university_from_name
      self.university = university_from_name
      self.company = nil if persisted?
    else
      self.company = Company.where(name: name).first_or_create 
      self.university = nil if persisted?
    end
  end
end
```

As a side note, I think this implementation may be improved by using a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) instead of plain associations and custom setter and getter methods.

Comment: This is work for new record but when i try to edit a record that already use company name and try to chose a university name this university name is not saved

Comment: That's why I strongly suggest moving towards a polymorphic association, or any similar implementation. This way, you'll get deeper and deeper in the rabbit hole ... but let's see if my edit fixes your problem (which is that you'll have both ``University`` and ``Company`` associated to the edited record).

Comment: Now I'm getting the opposite when try the university name persist but not company name in edit

Comment: i think this will work because i already change my code to this one and it is working       if university_from_name
      self.university = university_from_name
      self.company = nil
    else 
      self.university = nil
      self.company = Company.where(name: name).first_or_create
    end

Comment: it is working thank you verry much but can you  tell me what is the advantage of polymorphic association over this method

Comment: It's a much clear implementation to read and to mantain. You have a method ``company_name`` that actually doesn't always gives you a ``Company.name``, which is misleading and will cause you pain in the future for sure. You only have one associated model, so you don't need to clear the other just as we just had to do ... to name some of the advantages. Anyway, this works, so you may think of a refactor later on.